# How do I iterate through a vector that has struct pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, struct, iteration

```
struct some_struct{
     some_struct *pointer_to_another_struct;
     int a;
some_struct(int value ) :a (value), pointer_to_another(NULL)()
};

...

vector<some_struct *> tree;
...

for ( auto it = tree.begin(); it != tree.end();  ++it) {
     it->a=10;
}
```

This apparently is not the correct way to iterate through a vector of struct pointers because my compiler is giving me errors. How can I fix it? Also, is there anything I should worry about when I store pointers in a vector?

Comment: Always specify *exact* error messages.

Comment: It is the right way to iterate, but not the right way to access the element. You have to dereference the iterator: `(*it)->a=10`

Answer (score 6):

Just dereference the iterator first:

```
(*it)->a=10;
```

In your code, you are trying to access element `a` of the `vector<some_struct *>::iterator`, which doesn't make sense.  You want to the dereference the iterator to access the struct pointers:

```
some_struct * ptr = *it;
```

Alternatively, since you have C++11, it probably makes more sense to just use a range for loop:

```
for (auto ptr : tree)
{
   ...
}
```

which is equivalent to:

```
for (some_struct * ptr : tree)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Since the auto keyword is being used, I would assume that C++11 is enabled.  That would let you iterate the entire vector using a range-based for loop.  This would give you the pointer instead of an iterator.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use C++11 you can use a range-based for loop instead

```
for (auto element : tree)
{
     element->a=10;    // element is a some_struct*
}
```

Otherwise, as written, you need to first de-reference your iterator to get at the underlying pointer.

Answer (score 2):

dwcanillas answere is of course correct, but another alternative way would be using for-each if c++11 is available:

```
for(some_struct* ptr : tree) {
    ptr->a = 10;
}
```